# How can I modify Docker's internal IP on a Mac?

Tags: docker

Took me 20mins until I realized we have an internal subnet of 172.17.0.x where I work. How can I modify my Docker instance on my laptop to use something other than the default address?

Comment: Using Docker for Mac?

Comment: yep. i've found various articles regarding linux but have yet to find one for Mac.